# File not downloading even though it says it did

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, webclient

I have a problem where a file won't download, even though it shows as completed.

The file is not showing in the location where it's supposed to be be downloaded to.

This is my code:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.ColumnIndex == 2)
    {
        int rowIndex = e.RowIndex;
        DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex];
        string value1 = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        wc.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(AtlasCompleted);
        Uri fileUrl = new Uri(value1);
        Beta = fileUrl;
        //Console.WriteLine(FormPopup.Variables.Location1.Length);
        if (FormPopup.Variables.Location1 != null && FormPopup.Variables.Location1.Length >= 5)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(FormPopup.Variables.Location1);
            Console.WriteLine(fileUrl);
            wc.DownloadFileAsync(fileUrl, FormPopup.Variables.Location1);
            //MessageBox.Show(fileUrl.ToString() + "               " + FormPopup.Variables.Location1);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: No file location specified.");
            FormPopup form = new FormPopup();
            form.Show(this);
        }

    }
}

private void AtlasCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(Beta.ToString() + "               " + FormPopup.Variables.Location1);
}
```

The file should download, but it's not downloading or appearing in the location specified.

If anyone can help that would be great, its really confusing me.

Thanks for the replies :D

Comment: Where do you specify the path to save the file under? Is AtlasCompleted called?

Comment: I specify the path in another form, it is saved under FormPopup.Variables.Location1, it is showing the correct path and AtlasCompleted is being called but the file is no where to be found.

Comment: I have noticed one thing, the program seems to be instantly completing  it. It seems to take no time at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WebClient code is fine and it should download the file without any issues. Just ensure that your file Uri is correct (paste the uri into browser and see its correct). Path to save file on local system should be valid (folders included in path must exists) and regular user must have permissions to write.

To test it further, first use the hard-coded values:

```
wc.DownloadFileAsync("File Uril","File path at local system");
```

Example:

```
wc.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://example.com/myfile.txt"), @"d:\myfile.txt");
```

Double check your variables for Uri and location because there is no magic that would prevent downloading besides invalid parameters.

Additionally, add some error logging/Exception handling so it tells you what happened.

```
private void AtlasCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
if(e.Error !=null)
    Console.WriteLine(e.Error.Message);
     else
   Console.WriteLine("Completed");

    MessageBox.Show(Beta.ToString() + "               " + FormPopup.Variables.Location1);
}
```